# With dual-monitors, how can I set up one screen so it won't affect the other?

Tags: multiple-monitors, microsoft-powerpoint

At work, we have a dual monitor to check-in at. One screen displays a PowerPoint, while the other displays the check-in. Every time a person clicks on the right hand screen to check in, the PowerPoint stops.

How can I set it up so that the PowerPoint continues to play even after somebody clicks on the right screen?

Comment: The details you've provided aren't enough to answer. What operating system do you use? What program is running in the other screen? ...

Comment: I'm sorry - I am not that great with computers. The other screen has Google Chrome up on it for check in. As for the operating system, Microsoft Windows I believe.

Comment: For us to be able to help, we need to know what version of PowerPoint and what the slideshow settings are. Without more details, we will only be guessing. Go Blue!

Comment: @CharlieRB, it's PowerPoint 2010. Everything listed below is checked off. Each slide changes automatically, but once you even click on the secondary monitor, the powerpoint stops, as if you're clicking on both screens. Love that, go Blue!!!

Comment: I'm sorry I am so unclear by the way -- I don't really know how to use anything but a Mac

Answer (score 10):

Adjust your slideshow settings to run in a window. To do this, go to `Setup Slideshow`.

[image]

Set it to loop until you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. If you have the choice under multiple monitors to uncheck `Show Presenter View` and select the monitor you want it shown on *(I only have one monitor, so mine is greyed out in the image)*. If you do not have a choice for monitor, you will need to drag the window to the monitor you want it showing on.

[image]

Click <kbd>OK</kbd>, then save your presentation. Now when you run the slideshow, it will be in a window. Maximize the window and open your browser on the other monitor.

Since I only have one monitor resized the window and the presentation played while I am typing this.

Answer (score 0):

On the slide show tab, on monitors, set your monitor to primary monitor, and untick the box underneath it that says use presenter view.

Comment: Can you give specific instructions with one or more screenshots? How is your answer an improvement on the answer given years ago?

Answer (score 0):

Go to slide show menu and select "Set Up Slide Show" under Set Up group.

A Set Up Show window appear, there deselect the check box "Use Presenter View" under Multiple monitors section.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned...after following all this advice on countless forums I can state categorically that if you have two monitors you cannot stop powerpoint operating on two monitors.

It is a curse

I can only work on a single monitor system as a consequence.

Powerpoint on two monitors is cumbersome, ineffective, confusing and unnecessary.

I have lectured for over 40 years and I do not see the need for it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).